# Jsp - two pages in one

Tags: jsp, custom-error-pages, login-control

So I just started writing my first code in jsp.

I made a login page that the user writes his username and his password and if either of them does not exists in the database(MySQl),it print's a message in the same page(the user thinks it's the same page).

I did that by sending the information to a file (looks in the database),and if the information is correct then goes to the next page and if its wrong goes to an error page.

Now my question to you is that if I have two pages with the same code(Login.jsp and ErrorLogin.jsp) and the only difference is the extra error message how to join them?

can I avoid my the two same pages? :/
My first thinking was to put an if statement but its confusing in this language.

Here is the 2 files I have created(I don't think that the Validation_Login.jsp is important for this,but if it is let me know to upload it)

---

### Login.jsp

```
<body> 

        <form action="Validation_Login.jsp">             
                <font size="+3"> Login </font>
                <br/><br/>

                <div>
                    USERNAME: <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="firstname"/>
                    <br/><br/>
                </div>

                <div>
                    PASSWORD: <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password" />
                    <br/><br/>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="login" />
                </div>
        </form>

        <form action="Create_Account.jsp">
                <input type="submit" value="Create_Account">
        </form>

    </body>
```

---

### ErrorLogin.jsp

```
<body>         
        <form action="Validation_Login.jsp" >
                <font size="+3"> Login </font>
                <br/><br/>

                <div>
                    USERNAME: <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="firstname"/>
                    <br/><br/>
                </div>

                <div>
                    PASSWORD: <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
                    <br/><br/>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="login" />
                </div>
        </form>

        <form action="Create_Account.jsp">
            <input type="submit" value="Create_Account">
        </form>

        <div id="message">
            Wrong UserName Or Password
            <br/>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Please Try Again
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Did you try using the include statement? You can use it to include content of another jsp page into this jsp page.

Comment: Then, in the error page you can include the template (stuff that is common for both pages) and just add the error message beneath it.

Comment: Yes I thought of it 1 hour after I asked this question :D
And I did it like that!!

Comment: Cool...maybe, for the sake of other people looking, I could write a more elaborate answer and you can accept it, as it solves your (and other peoples) problem?

Comment: ok, I have no problem with that

Comment: hey...I added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is using jstl tag "include"

```
<jsp:include page="./path-to-template/template_name.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="content" value="content_page_name"></jsp:param>
</jsp:include>
```

To make this possible, the content of the "template_name" jsp page should be:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-6"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>MyGrowth - Track Education While in Migration</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <%@include file="header.jsp" %>
            <jsp:include page="../content/${param.content}.jsp"></jsp:include>
            </div>                      
        </body>
    <%@include file="footer.jsp"%>
</html>
```

The crucial part is where you include the page you got from the parameter:

```
       <jsp:include page="../content/${param.content}.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

So, when we pass the page with name 'content_page_name' to the template page, then that page is inserted at the place where the 'include' tag is, in the 'template' page.

*NOTE: The `content` pages should contain only html body elements (since the head is already defined in the template page.

Comment: @george nikitas
Did you find this answer to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by setting some flag in the code that checks the login (in the page you haven't posted) and then check for this flag in login.jsp to determine whether  or not to show the error message.

You can use the Java Standard Tag Library to do this.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm

In both JSPs add the directive:

`<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>`

On failed login:

`<c:set var="loginFailed value="true" scope="request"/>`

on the login page:

```
<c:if test="${loginFailed eq true}">
        <div id="message">
            Wrong UserName Or Password. Please Try Again
        </div>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this solution works well instead of having multiple files use `if elseif else` statements
let me explain the flow
first let me explain the flow of the program

> jsp is a server side program and it starts its execution from the beginning

flow

> declare a variable and initialize 0 to it

use  tag with the action # i.e. to refresh the page when submit is clicked

```
<form action="#" method="get">
```

> by default inside the program you will be checking for the user credentials

if user credentials match just go with the flow
else initialize the flag variable to 1

```
<% if(flag==1)
{%>
<html>your code xyz</html>
<% }
%>
```

thankyou!